# Protractor sendKeys and Angular ng-touched event

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm testing my webapp that has an input that when a key is press will trigger an event that unhides the next row of elements.  Upon inspection, I'm noticing that that `class` attribute of that `input` element transitions from `ng-untouched` to `ng-touched` when I manually test the element.  However, when I use the `sendKeys` method, the class remains as `ng-untouched`, but it does become `ng-dirty`.

Is sendKeys bugged or is there another method to trigger this? Or is this a bug with regards to my developer having done the angular part wrong?

**System Environment:**

- Mac OS: El Capitan
- angular@2.0.0-rc.1
- protractor@3.3.0
- webdriver-manager

  - status: selenium standalone is 2.52.0
  - chromedriver is 2.21

Comment: Try element.click()

SendKeys literally inserts keys into the field via manipulating the element via the DOM, which sidesteps the way the browser receives input from the user, with mouse clicks / tabs etc. So to actually trigger that, you need to also cause the browser to focus on the element. click() might do the trick.

There used to be a Selenium function called .focus() that would more explicitly do this to an element but I don't find it in Protractor's docs.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try. I hadn't thought of prefacing the sendKeys with a click.  Selenium, if I remember, you have to use a bit of javascript to cause a blur.  I'll just stick with clicking, or perhaps simulate a keydown / keyup event.

Comment: Yeah, I seem to recall something called "fireEvent" and you could do element.fireEvent("blur"), etc.

Comment: Hey @Machtyn, i have same issue. can you suggest best solution you get?

Comment: @UttamPanara Using the `element(by.css('input')).click()` should work to change `ng-untouched` to `ng-touched`. I don't remember exactly how I fixed it in my situation.